# Retrieving selected columns based on a many-to-many relationship expressed along with an extra column in the join table using JPA criteria

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

I have three tables in MySQL database.

```
zone_table

zone_id (PK)
zone_name
transporter_id (FK references the transporter table - unrelated here).
```

---

```
weight

weight_id (PK)
weight
```

---

```
zone_charge

zone_id (FK refernces zone_table) |
weight_id (FK references weight)  | composite primary key.
charge                            | extra column in join.
```

Since a many-to-many relationship between `zone_table` and `weight` is expressed by the `zone_charge` table with an **extra column** in it (which is `charge`), an embeddable class `ZoneChargePK` representing the composite primary key has been created.

With this relationship, I need to retrieve a list of rows consisting of three fields, `weight_id` and `weight` from the `weight` table and `charge` from the `zone_charge` table **for a given zone**.

The native **SQL** would be as follows.

```
SELECT w.weight_id, w.weight, zc.charge
FROM weight w
LEFT OUTER JOIN zone_charge zc ON w.weight_id=zc.weight_id
WHERE zc.zone_id=?
ORDER BY w.weight ASC
```

The corresponding **JPQL** would be as under.

```
SELECT w.weightId, w.weight, zc.charge 
FROM Weight w 
LEFT JOIN w.zoneChargeSet zc 
WITH zc.zone.zoneId=:id 
ORDER BY w.weight
```

I would like the same thing to be expressed by JPA criteria query, since this query would, in turn be generated dynamically. I have left with the following  incomplete criteria query.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple>criteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Root<Weight> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Weight.class));

SetJoin<Weight, ZoneCharge> join = root.join(Weight_.zoneChargeSet, JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(Weight_.weightId), root.get(Weight_.weight), join.get(ZoneCharge_.zoneTable));
TypedQuery<Tuple> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Tuple> tuples = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

But this results in an inner join between `zone_table` and `zone_charge` in addition to a left join between `zone_charge` and `weight`. The generated SQL query looks like the following.

```
select
    weight0_.weight_id as col_0_0_,
    weight0_.weight as col_1_0_,
    zonecharge1_.zone_id as col_2_0_,
    zonetable2_.zone_id as zone1_34_, 
    zonetable2_.transporter_id as transpor3_34_,
    zonetable2_.zone_name as zone2_34_ 
from
    social_networking.weight weight0_ 
left outer join
    social_networking.zone_charge zonecharge1_ 
        on weight0_.weight_id=zonecharge1_.weight_id 
inner join
    social_networking.zone_table zonetable2_ 
        on zonecharge1_.zone_id=zonetable2_.zone_id
```

It should actually be,

```
select
    weight0_.weight_id as col_0_0_,
    weight0_.weight as col_1_0_,
    zonecharge1_.charge as col_2_0_        
from
    social_networking.weight weight0_ 
left outer join
    social_networking.zone_charge zonecharge1_ 
        on weight0_.weight_id=zonecharge1_.weight_id
```

Except for `where` and `order by`. So how would the actual criteria query look like?

---

**EDIT :**

The `ZoneTable` entity (**only if needed**):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zone_table", catalog = "social_networking", schema = "", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"zone_id"})})
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ZoneTable.findAll", query = "SELECT z FROM ZoneTable z"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ZoneTable.findByZoneId", query = "SELECT z FROM ZoneTable z WHERE z.zoneId = :zoneId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ZoneTable.findByZoneName", query = "SELECT z FROM ZoneTable z WHERE z.zoneName = :zoneName")})
public class ZoneTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "zone_id", nullable = false)
    private Long zoneId;
    @Column(name = "zone_name", length = 45)
    private String zoneName;
    @JoinColumn(name = "transporter_id", referencedColumnName = "transporter_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Transporter transporterId;



    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "zoneTable", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ZoneCharge> zoneChargeSet;   //<--------------------------


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "zoneId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Country> countrySet;
}
```

---

The `Weight` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "weight", catalog = "social_networking", schema = "", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"weight_id"})})
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Weight.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM Weight w"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Weight.findByWeightId", query = "SELECT w FROM Weight w WHERE w.weightId = :weightId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Weight.findByWeight", query = "SELECT w FROM Weight w WHERE w.weight = :weight")})
public class Weight implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "weight_id", nullable = false)
    private Long weightId;
    @Column(name = "weight", precision = 35, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal weight;



    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "weight", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ZoneCharge> zoneChargeSet;    //<-------------------------
}
```

---

The `ZoneCharge` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zone_charge", catalog = "social_networking", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ZoneCharge.findAll", query = "SELECT z FROM ZoneCharge z"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ZoneCharge.findByZoneId", query = "SELECT z FROM ZoneCharge z WHERE z.zoneChargePK.zoneId = :zoneId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ZoneCharge.findByWeightId", query = "SELECT z FROM ZoneCharge z WHERE z.zoneChargePK.weightId = :weightId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "ZoneCharge.findByCharge", query = "SELECT z FROM ZoneCharge z WHERE z.charge = :charge")})
public class ZoneCharge implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected ZoneChargePK zoneChargePK;

    @Column(name = "charge", precision = 35, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal charge;

    @JoinColumn(name = "zone_id", referencedColumnName = "zone_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ZoneTable zoneTable;

    @JoinColumn(name = "weight_id", referencedColumnName = "weight_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Weight weight;
```

---

The `ZoneChargePK` entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class ZoneChargePK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "zone_id", nullable = false)
    private long zoneId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "weight_id", nullable = false)
    private long weightId;
}
```

According to this relationship, the JPQL query as shown above works correctly.

<sup>It is not a social networking project. It was just originally intended. Therefore it was named such. It is about a shopping site.</sup>

Comment: How have you defined the relationships between the JPA entities?

Comment: Edited to be a more verbose question, sorry.

Comment: In your select, you seem to be using join.get(ZoneCharge_.zoneTable), aren't you after join.get(ZoneCharge_.charge) instead?  You also need the where clause criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("zoneChargePK").get("zoneId"), criteriaBuilder.parameter(java.lang.Long.class, "param"))  Or something like it. The query would then need to pass in "param" using query.setParameter("param", zoneIdValue)

Comment: Next time please add only the mappings relevant to the question

Comment: @Chris : You may add it as an answer. It turned out to be true. I actually needed `AND` with join and not `WHERE`. I overlooked this in this question and posted a new question but the comment answers this question.